# "In real life" vs "In a real life" vs "In the real life"

Tags: articles

Should I use an article in such phrases, and if I should - which one? Examples:

1. In [?] real life you shouldn't do that.
2. In [?] real life things aren't so simple.
3. In [?] real life it's almost useless.

Comment: In these examples, it isn't, so no article is needed.

Comment: I've re-read the discussion you've referenced and yes, looks like that's my case, I don't need an article here. Thank you!